# Heap sort save results to file

Tags: c, file, heapsort

I've a problem with saving results to file. This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define DUZO 100000000
int heap_size;
int tab[DUZO];
FILE* wejscie;
FILE* wyjscie;

void rand1(int tmp){
    int i, y;

    for(i = 0; i < tmp; i++){
        y = rand();
        fprintf(wejscie, "%i ", y);
    }
}

void heapify(int start){
    int l, r, largest, pom;

    l = 2*start + 1;
    r = 2*start + 2;

    if((l < heap_size) && (tab[l] > tab[start]))
        largest = l;
    else
        largest = start;

    if((r <  heap_size) && (tab[r] > tab[largest]))
        largest = r;
    if(largest != start){
        pom = tab[start];
        tab[start] = tab[largest];
        tab[largest] = pom;

        heapify(largest);
    }
}

void build_max(){
    int lenght, i;
    lenght = heap_size;

    for(i = ((lenght - 1)/2); i >= 0; --i){
        heapify(i);
    }
}

void heap_sort(){
    int i;
    build_max();


    for(i = heap_size-1; i > 0; --i) {
        int tmp = tab[0];
        tab[0] = tab[i];
        tab[i] = tmp;
        --heap_size;
        heapify(0);
    }
}

int main(void){

    wejscie=fopen("wejscie.dat","rw");
    wyjscie=fopen("wyjscie.dat","w");

    int i, tmp;

    printf("Podaj ilosc liczb do sortowania: ");
    scanf("%i", &heap_size);
    tmp = heap_size;

    rand1(tmp);

    printf("Pseudolosowe liczby do posortowania: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < tmp; i++){
        fscanf(wejscie,"%i", &tab[i]);
        printf("%i\n", tab[i]);
    }

    heap_sort();

    fclose(wejscie);

    printf("\nPosortowany ciag: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < tmp; i++){
        printf("%i\n", tab[i]);
        fprintf(wyjscie, "%i\n", tab[i]);
    }

    fclose(wyjscie);
return 0;   
}
```

When I create file wejscie.dat program work good, but when I don't to create it with rand function it doesn't work and doesn't save results to file wejscie.dat. Please help me.

Comment: Please check that `fopen()` succeeds before using the return value; you are likely to crash if it fails, but even if you don't, it is still undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

**wejscie.dat** is your input file. Apparently you're writing random values in to it and reading it again to load the `tab[]`. You can skip creating the file by initialising the array in `rand1()` itself.

**wyjscie.dat** is your output file not **wejscie.dat**

PS:
Open input file in `"w+"` mode and `rewind` before reading from it again.

```
    wejscie = fopen("wejscie.dat", "w+");
    if (NULL == wejscie) {
        fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: Opening Input file Err[%d] Error[%s]", errno, strerror(errno));
        //Formal error handling
        return (-1);
    }
    //...
    //...
    rand1(tmp);
    rewind (wejscie); 
    fprintf( stderr, "Pseudolosowe liczby do posortowania: \n");
```

Comment: yes but i've to make this with file wejscie.dat and wyjscie.dat

Comment: Yes i known. wejscie.dat is an input file and with this file tab[] is filling, then make heap_sort and the in the end results are copy to wyjscie.dat

Comment: Then who's supposed to provide the input values? a) the program itself during run-time. b) the user updates input file before running the program.

Comment: user say how many number wont to sort, the function rand1() should generate random numer and save it to file wejscie.dat. The Hep sort sort this number and results is saving to file wyjscie.dat